# Transition matrices conversion

Tags: linear-algebra

(a) Suppose that B1, B2, and B3 are bases for a vector space V and that
$$
P_{B_1 \to B_2} 
= \begin{bmatrix}3&1\\5&2\end{bmatrix}, 
\qquad 
P_{B_2 \to B_3} 
= \begin{bmatrix}7&2\\4&-1\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Find $P_{B_3 \to B_1}$.

(b) Let $B_1 = \{(1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 0), (1, 0, 0)\}$ and suppose that 
$$
P = \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&3&2\\0&1&1\end{bmatrix}
$$
is the transition matrix from $B_1$ to some other basis $B_2$. Find $B_2$.

For part **(a)** how do I go about doing the transition matrix from $B_3$ to $B_1$ without knowing the elements of $B_1$, $B_2$, and $B_3$.

For part **(b)** what operation would I use to find $B_2$. I know that $P_{B_1 \to B_2}$, but I do not know the basis of $B_2$.

Comment: I edited your question to demonstrate $\LaTeX$ mark up that's used on this site.  Have a look, so that your questions can be more readable in the future.  Here's a tutorial, by the way:  http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/6509

Answer (score 1):

(a) Notice that each of the two matrices are invertible as their determinant is nonzero. Now convince yourself that if you find the matrix $P_{B_3\rightarrow B_1}$ then you will have $P_{B_3\rightarrow B_1}P_{B_2\rightarrow B_3}P_{B_1\rightarrow B_2}$ is the identity matrix with respect to the basis $B_1$. This implies that $P_{B_3\rightarrow B_1}=(P_{B_2\rightarrow B_3}P_{B_1\rightarrow B_2})^{-1} = (P_{B_1\rightarrow B_2})^{-1}(P_{B_2\rightarrow B_3})^{-1}$.

(b) Suppose that the basis $B_2$ is $\{w_1,w_2,w_3\}$. Notice that we have the following three equations: 
$$
P((1,1,1)) = w_1
$$
$$
P((1,1,0)) = 3w_2 +w_3
$$
$$
P((1,0,0)) = 2w_2 +w_3
$$

Use these three equations to get the basis $B_2$